# Correct order of Postgres maintenance

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing, vacuum

I have a big table which is suffering from Index bloating because a lot of rows are frequently updated. I'm also in the process of deleting a big number of rows.

What would the correct order of executing the following tasks in order to recover disk space?

- Vacuum, mark dead tuples as free for database reuse, doesn't return
  space to system.
- Vacuum Full, rewrites table reducing table bloat,
  returns space to system.
- Reindex, rewrites indexes reducing index
  bloat, returns space to system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since PostgreSQL 9.0 a `VACUUM FULL` should return disc space optimally (just like [CLUSTER](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-cluster.html) does). I quote the release notes for 9.0 from the current manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/release-9-0.html):

> New implementation of VACUUM FULL. This command now rewrites the
>   entire table and indexes, rather than moving individual rows to
>   compact space. It is substantially faster in most cases, and no longer
>   results in index bloat.

Note that it is not normally necessary or even advisable to run `VACUUM FULL`. It may slow down UPDATEs if you remove all wiggle room for HOT updates and such from the data pages.

Comment: Yes, I knew that VACUUM FULL had been rewritten, what I wasn't aware of was that indexes are also rewritten.
Still, my questions still stands, what would be the preferably actions and order of execution in a situation like the described?

Comment: @Gothmog: In order to recover disk space, it's just that: `VACUUM FULL` or `CLUSTER`. Nothing else needed. I would `VACUUM FULL ANALYZE` for the additional purpose of getting current statistics. No `REINDEX` needed. Normally, if it's not about recovering disc space and you did not just delete large parts of the table, you should just use `VACUUM ANALYZE`.